# Retrieve Outlook email messages by range of time

Tags: python, outlook, date-formatting

I'm trying to get emails from my Outlook inbox but filtered with a time range (emails received between 4 PM and 8 AM for example. I begin with this code below but don't know how to finish it. I use this doc for the [Outlook API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.senton).

```
import win32com.client as client

# startup outlook instance
outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

# get namespace so that we can access folders
namespace = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')

account = namespace.Folders['MyAccountName']

# get the inbox folder, specifically
inbox = account.Folders['Inbox']

Filter = ("[SentOn] > 'WhatToPlaceHereAsAStartHour???' AND "
          "[SentOn] < 'WhatToPlaceHereAsAEndHour???'")
# I tried somethin like '16:00' and '8:00' but didnt work...

Items = inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
Item = Items.GetFirst()

print(Item.subject)
```

Answer (score 0):

The datetime values must include both date *and* time, e.g. `"01/09/2022 16:00"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what if I want all the mails from 01/01 to 01/05 but only between 4PM and 8AM ?

Comment: You need to specify the whole date with a different time values.

Comment: See [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/) for the sample code.

Comment: You would need to create 5 restrictions for each day separated by "or"

Answer (score 0):

Although dates and times are typically stored with a `Date` format, the `Find` and `Restrict` methods require that the date and time be converted to a string representation. To make sure that the date is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, for example, you can use the `Format` function available in VBA. The following example creates a filter to find all contacts that have been modified after January 15, 2020 at 3:30 P.M.

```
sFilter = "[LastModificationTime] > '" & Format("1/15/2020 3:30pm", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
```

Read more about the `Restrict` method in the [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/) article.

Comment: Thanks for reply ! The format is ok for me using something like "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm" :)